# JavaScript Equivalent of C# ToDictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functional-programming

I am looking for a way to take the following list:

```
directory = [
    {
        name: "Albert",
        age: 40,
        gender: "M"
    },
    {
        name: "Suzanne",
        age: 27,
        gender: "F"
    },
    {
        name: "Robert",
        age: 19,
        gender: "M"
    },
    {
        name: "Connie",
        age: 87,
        gender: "F"
    }
]
```

and make a dictionary on the key `name`:

```
dictionary = {
    "Albert": {
        name: "Albert",
        age: 40,
        gender: "M"
    },
    "Suzanne": {
        name: "Suzanne",
        age: 27,
        gender: "F"
    },
    "Robert": {
        name: "Robert",
        age: 19,
        gender: "M"
    },
    "Connie": {
        name: "Connie",
        age: 87,
        gender: "F"
    }
}
```

This is similar to the C# [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary) method.  I know I could do something like iterate over `directory` in a `for` loop or `.each` call, and modify the value of `dictionary` each iteration.  I would prefer, however, to make a functional programming-like assignment instead, e.g.

```
dictionary = directory.toDictionary(p => p.name);
```

Does such a method exist, say within ES6 or lodash?

Comment: You can do it with `.reduce()`.

Comment: Note the first structure allows more than one entry for the same name, while the one you want don't.

Comment: [linq.js](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq/blob/master/linq.js) offers a `toDictionary` method.

Comment: You can write it. Think: extension methods; just a warning, in JS they are global, so be careful about collisions with other libraries/ES6/7/8/9... But ultimately, a good old `for(let i=0; i<array.length; ++i)` loop is still the fastest way to iterate an Array.

Comment: @Shidersz you are correct.  I had originally thought of asking for an equivalent of the `ToLookup` method, which would allow for duplicated key entries.  The above scenario is a re-representation of the actual application, in which there will only be unique dictionary keys.

Comment: you should be using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) - it was specifically designed for creating a lookup table like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map key and value and create an object from this arrays with (upcoming) [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
var directory = [{ name: "Albert", age: 40, gender: "M" }, { name: "Suzanne", age: 27, gender: "F" }, { name: "Robert", age: 19, gender: "M" }, { name: "Connie", age: 87, gender: "F" }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(directory.map(o => [o.name, o]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A classic approach

```js
var directory = [{ name: "Albert", age: 40, gender: "M" }, { name: "Suzanne", age: 27, gender: "F" }, { name: "Robert", age: 19, gender: "M" }, { name: "Connie", age: 87, gender: "F" }],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...directory.map(o => ({ [o.name]: o })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 6):

Javascript's [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) closely resembles a dictionary. Its instances sport handy `has`, `get`, `set`, `keys`, `values` methods. It's also directly iterable via a `forEach` method.

You can construct a `Map` using an array of "key-value-pairs". (in quotes, because in reality we're using arrays in some tuple-like fashion).

To create a `Map` to use as a dictionary, you'd do:

```js
const directory=[{name:"Albert",age:40,gender:"M"},{name:"Suzanne",age:27,gender:"F"},{name:"Robert",age:19,gender:"M"},{name:"Connie",age:87,gender:"F"}];

const myDict = new Map(
  directory.map(p => [p.name, p])
);

console.log("Has Albert:", myDict.has("Albert"))

myDict.forEach(p => { console.log(`${p.name} has age ${p.age}`) });
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no specific built-in but it's easy with `.reduce()`:

```
let dict = directory.reduce((d, v) => (d[v.name] = v, d), {});
```

As pointed out in a good comment on the question, one thing you need to consider is the meaning of duplicate names. Is that a "bad data" situation? Should there be an array of names for such duplicates? Questions like that are specific the the data structure and its purpose in your specific application.

Comment: It seems `reduce` [outperforms](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/9268/0/objectfromentries-vs-reduce#latest_results_block) `Object.fromEntries`.

Comment: This looks more elegant than the `Object.assign` way.

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked by `lodash` solution too, you can use the [.keyBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#keyBy) method of that library.

```js
const directory = [{name:"Albert",age:40,gender:"M"},{name:"Suzanne",age:27,gender:"F"},{name:"Robert",age:19,gender:"M"},{name:"Connie",age:87,gender:"F"}];

console.log(_.keyBy(directory, o => o.name));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.14/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

However, as I say on a commentary, the first structure allows more than one entry for the same name, while the resulting one don't. So, in the case that the `directory` array includes multiple objects with the same name, you will only get the last of they on the resulting data.

Answer (score 2):

You could `reduce` the array. Use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to add each name as a property

```js
const directory=[{name:"Albert",age:40,gender:"M"},{name:"Suzanne",age:27,gender:"F"},{name:"Robert",age:19,gender:"M"},{name:"Connie",age:87,gender:"F"}],
    output = directory.reduce((r, o) => Object.assign(r, { [o.name]: o }), {})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: This is a good solution, since it supports elderly browsers and Js standards. Object.fromEntries will require ES2017 lib to be imported, if you use tsconfig and Angular for example.

Comment: Isn't `Object.assign` going to make a copy of the object at every iteration?

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde no, it just copies the properties to the target object `r` and returns `r`.

Comment: You're right, I read the docs wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I added an implementation of ToDictionary which allows you to define a key selector also and allow duplicate values per key which will be saved into an array if there are many values. The method is part of version 1.0.14 of my library "simpletslinq" hosted on Npmjs.com

Note that my code is written in Typescript, so you must run tsc typescript compiler on it to create a true Javscript equivalent. In its core, we are using the map function to create the dictionary. The added typescript stuff is to add type checking..

```
 if (!Array.prototype.ToDictionary) {
  Array.prototype.ToDictionary = function <T>(keySelector: (arg: T) => any): any {
    let hash = {};
    this.map(item => {
      let key = keySelector(item);
      if (!(key in hash)) {
        hash[key] = item;
      }
      else {
        if (!(Array.isArray(hash[key]))) {
          hash[key] = [hash[key]];
        }
        hash[key].push(item);
      }
    });
    return hash;
  }
}
```

A spec (test) for this code then looks like this:

```
  it('can apply method ToDictionary on an array, allowing specificaton of a key selector for the dictionary object', () => {
    let heroes = [{ name: "Han Solo", age: 47, gender: "M" }, { name: "Leia", age: 29, gender: "F" }, { name: "Luke", age: 24, gender: "M" }, { name: "Lando", age: 47, gender: "M" }];
    let dictionaryOfHeroes = heroes.ToDictionary<Hero>(x => x.gender);

    let expectedDictionary = {
      "F": {
        name: "Leia", age: 29, gender: "F"
      },
      "M": [
        { name: "Han Solo", age: 47, gender: "M" },
        { name: "Luke", age: 24, gender: "M" },
        { name: "Lando", age: 47, gender: "M" }
      ]
    };
    expect(dictionaryOfHeroes).toEqual(expectedDictionary);
  });
```

[image: ToDictionary spec output on NpmRunKit]